# Alternative to IF EXISTS in an Access query

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access, if-statement

I'm developing a website in ASP.NET using C# with an Access database, but I'm having trouble using a query that needs to check:

- if some information exists in the table then update,
- if not then insert into the table

I have the code in SQL which is not accepted in Access. I want to know if there's another way to make it or if Access can use an alternative to the `if exists` clause. Here is the SQL code:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE ShoppingCartAjoutProduits
(@CartID char(36),
@ProduitID int,
@Attributs char(255))
As
IF EXISTS
(SELECT CartID
FROM ShoppingCart
WHERE ProduitID = @ProduitID AND CartID = @CartID)
UPDATE ShoppingCart
SET Quantite = Quantite + 1
WHERE ProduitID = @ProduitID AND CartID = @CartID
ELSE
IF EXISTS (SELECT titre FROM livres WHERE NumLivre = @NumLivre)
INSERT INTO ShoppingCart (CartID, ProduitID, Attributs, Quantite, DateAjoute)
VALUES (@CartID, @ProduitID, @Attributs, 1, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access SQL does not support procedural code; VBA takes care of that in Access. However, you could always perform those operations in your C# code using something like this:

```csharp
using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(), cmd2 = new OleDbCommand())
{
    string cartID = "Cart1";               //
    int produitID = 1;                     // test data
    string attributs = "je ne sais quoi";  //
    int numLivre = 1;                      //

    cmd.Connection = con;  // existing OleDbConnection, already .Open()
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText =
            "SELECT * FROM ShoppingCart " +
            "WHERE cartID=? AND produitID=?";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarWChar, 255).Value = cartID;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.Integer).Value = produitID;
    var da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
    var cb = new OleDbCommandBuilder(da);
    cb.QuotePrefix = "["; cb.QuoteSuffix = "]";
    var dt = new System.Data.DataTable("ShoppingCart");
    da.Fill(dt);
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        int n = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0]["Quantite"]);
        dt.Rows[0]["Quantite"] = ++n;
    }
    else
    {
        cmd2.Connection = con;
        cmd2.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        cmd2.CommandText =
                "SELECT COUNT(*) AS n FROM livres WHERE NumLivre=?";
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", numLivre);
        int n = Convert.ToInt32(cmd2.ExecuteScalar());
        if (n > 0)
        {
            System.Data.DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["CartID"] = cartID;
            dr["ProduitID"] = produitID;
            dr["Attributs"] = attributs;
            dr["Quantite"] = 1;
            dr["DateAjoute"] = DateTime.Today;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
    }
    da.Update(dt);
}
```

Comment: hi Gord, sorry for the late reply, i haven't tested yet, i'm stuck somewhere else before i execute that methode... i'm trying first to create a cookie on the user's computer but i have an exception which i'm trying to solve and yet i haven't found a solution i'll let you

Comment: hi! Gord, your method helped me to have an idea, even if i didn't exactly write as you proposed... but it helped much to resolve my problem. but i think i had another problem with the "UPDATE" method from the code side(C#) if i try to call from it, it sends me no error message, but there's no change in the database. i don't understand why(i'm using procedures)!